# INSERT INTO NULLABLE FIELDS THROWING ERRORS WITH NULL VALUES

Tags: php, mysqli

MySQL v5.6.20; Table in question:

```
CREATE TABLE `invoices` (
    `INVOICE_NUMBER` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `INVOICE_DATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
    `PROJECT_NUMBER` smallint(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `CLIENT` tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
    `PROJECT_DESCRIPTION` tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
    `TOTAL_HOURS` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
    `SUBTOTAL` decimal(10,2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `TAX` decimal(10,2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `INVOICE_TOTAL` decimal(10,2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `DATE_SENT` date DEFAULT NULL,
    `DATE_RECEIVED` date DEFAULT NULL,
    `NOTES` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
    PRIMARY KEY (`INVOICE_NUMBER`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1005 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

And the pertinent bits of my process.php are:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $invNum = $_POST['invNum'];
    $invDate = $_POST['invDate'];
    $projNum = $_POST['projNum'];
    $client = $_POST['client'];
    $projDesc = $_POST['projDesc'];
    $totalHours = $_POST['totalHours'];
    $subTotal = $_POST['subTotal'];
    $tax = $_POST['tax'];
    $invTotal = $_POST['invTotal'];
    $dateSent = $_POST['dateSent'];
    $dateReceived = $_POST['dateReceived'];
    $notes = $_POST['notes'];
    $notes = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $notes);

echo "<div class=\"debug\">
        <table>
            <snip>( SUCCESSFULLY ECHOING ALL VARIABLES/VALUES )</snip>
        </table>
    </div>";


$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$query = "INSERT INTO Invoices
    (INVOICE_NUMBER, INVOICE_DATE, PROJECT_NUMBER, CLIENT, PROJECT_DESCRIPTION, TOTAL_HOURS, SUBTOTAL, TAX, INVOICE_TOTAL, DATE_SENT, DATE_RECEIVED, NOTES)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    INVOICE_NUMBER          = VALUES(INVOICE_NUMBER),
    INVOICE_DATE            = VALUES(INVOICE_DATE),
    PROJECT_NUMBER          = VALUES(PROJECT_NUMBER),
    CLIENT                  = VALUES(CLIENT),
    PROJECT_DESCRIPTION = VALUES(PROJECT_DESCRIPTION),
    TOTAL_HOURS             = VALUES(TOTAL_HOURS),
    SUBTOTAL                    = VALUES(SUBTOTAL),
    TAX                     = VALUES(TAX),
    INVOICE_TOTAL           = VALUES(INVOICE_TOTAL),
    DATE_SENT               = VALUES(DATE_SENT),
    DATE_RECEIVED           = VALUES(DATE_RECEIVED),
    NOTES                       = VALUES(NOTES)
    ";

if ($stmt->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt -> bind_param("ssssssdddsss", $invNum, $invDate, $projNum, $client, $projDesc, $totalHours, $subTotal, $tax, $invTotal, $dateSent, $dateReceived, $notes);
    echo $query; // debug
    $stmt -> execute();
    if ($mysqli->errno) {
        echo "<div class=\"error\"><br />INSERT failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error . "<br /><br /></div>";
    }
    else echo "Updated {$stmt->affected_rows} rows";

    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    $affRows = mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli);
    $my_id = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli); // last inserted ID (INVOICE_NUMBER)

    if (($result) && ($affRows)) {
        echo "<div class=\"debug\">
                    <p>
                        <strong>SUCCESS: RECORD INSERTED / UPDATED.</strong><br />
                        <strong>Records updated: " . $affRows . "</strong><br />
                        <strong>mysqli_insert_id = ".$my_id."</strong>
                    </p>
                </div>";
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

As to my original problem (which persists):

In my ignorance, I was unaware that empty strings are unacceptable in decimal & date fields. However, while I haven't changed the decimal fields they're now accepting empty strings, so I'm wondering if there's something under the prepared statement's hood that translates to zeroes? If so, it doesn't seem to apply to the date fields (in my table, both the decimal fields and the date fields are default null), which *are* throwing errors with an empty string. Evidently date fields behave differently?

If the only solution is a php function to check for empty strings and send null accordingly, then that's something I'll revisit; at this point my focus is js so if necessary I'll be tempted to simply change the field types, and get back to my js study.

Any insight or suggestions are greatly appreciated,

svs

Comment: If you're happy and you know it: SQL Injection!

Comment: @user1613163: Do. Escape. External. Input. Into. Your. Database. Before. Inserting.

Comment: @PeeHaa yes yes, I'll get to that. At one point in the dev of this personal project I had what I understood to be a legit way to globally implement mysql_escape_string but now I know that ain't kosher. Anyway, does that have anything to do with this issue? Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, let's take a look at the actual error message:

> "INSERT failed: (1366) Incorrect decimal value: '' for column 'TAX' at row 1"

It doesn't looks like it's complaining about a `NULL` value, it looks like it's complaining about a `decimal` value.  It even tells you the value it's complaining about:

```
''
```

An empty string isn't a `decimal`.  It also isn't `NULL`.  It's an empty string.  And you can't store a string in a `decimal` column, no matter how hard you try.

Looking at your query, it's pretty clear why this is happening:

```
....
TAX = '$tax'
....
```

What happens when `$tax` is empty?  Your query becomes this:

```
....
TAX = ''
....
```

There are a couple of different ways you can handle this.  You *could* put in a lot of conditional logic to build your query one field at a time, checking for a value in that field and omitting it entirely if the value is `NULL` (or include it with an explicit `NULL` in the query).  But a *better* approach (and one that would eliminate your glaring SQL injection vulnerability) would be to use a parameterized query and let the database engine handle the `NULL` values that you pass it.  (Just be sure to pass it `NULL` and not an empty string.)

Comment: If you have a simple, commented example handy, I would appreciate that. Of course I'm already googling it ;) Anyway, this is very helpful: you addressed my ignorance with useful info, Cheers!

Comment: Before I post a follow-up (new post): I've created a parameterized query, and still empty values are throwing errors. I would appreciate it if you would please elaborate on "let the database engine handle the NULL values ...", etc., 'cause I'm at a loss. (Assuming of course that whether or not a value is empty is random, per normal usage) Thank you much

Comment: @user1613163: What did you change the code to?  If you're still providing an empty string as the value then of course it's still going to result in an error.

Comment: Thanks again. I would have responded sooner but I have a 2011mbp. Please see revised question, cheers,

Comment: @user1613163: Um... I also have a 2011MBP, it's not *that* slow :) That is an interesting observation of a difference between numeric and date values. It kind of makes sense, numbers are much simpler than dates and easier to have default behaviors. It's probably worth a little more debugging to ensure that both of the parameters truly are empty strings and one of them isn't actually `null` in the PHP code. Overall the general advice still remains, it's worth validating the input before even communicating with the DB, creating an anti-corruption layer between the user inputs and the DB.

Comment: Thx again. And btw, the 2011mbp reference is re: the hours of restarting I suffer daily due to the ubiquitous GPU failure. Still waiting for T. Cook/Apple to acknowledge 30k+ users. I hope you're one of the lucky ones

Answer (score 0):

When you build a string like this . . .

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Invoices SET
...
TAX = '$tax',
...
```

and the PHP variable $tax equals, say, 3.02, the resulting string will look like this.

```
INSERT INTO Invoices SET ... TAX = '3.02' ...
```

Note that it tries to insert a string, not a numeric value. In general, this will still succeed.

But the PHP variable $tax equals `NULL` the resulting string will look like this.

```
INSERT INTO Invoices SET ... TAX = 'NULL' ...
```

The dbms tries to set the value for TAX to the *string* whose value is "NULL". That *string* is *not* the same thing as `NULL`.

Instead of building a query using string interpolation, use [mysqli()](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). These will also prevent SQL injection, which I'm sure you're soon to hear about.

Comment: Thx Mike. I have spent some time changing all the mysql statement to mysqli, did not know there was more to it vis a vis the query. Much appreciated that you explained the type-related aspect of my ignorance! Cheers.

Comment: p.s. David gets the accepted answer for inclusion of the phrase, 'parameterized query', but both answers are +1: on point & helpful